# Displaying empty chart using chart.js

Tags: django

Displaying empty chart i am using django 2.2 and chart.js. Is there some one who can help me . I can see the data in console.log but not in graph. I am working to solve this problem from hours. Or can you suggest other library for performing same task

**views.py**

```
class secondapi(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        newlabels = ['black', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple'],
        newdata =  [111, 22, 21 , 113, 14, 15],
        data = {'newlabels':newlabels, 'newdata':newdata, }
        return Response(data)
```

**html page**

```
<div class="container-fluid w-50 h-50 float-left">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas> 
  </div>




<script>
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
var newlabels = [] 
var newdata = []; 


$.ajax({     
    method: 'GET',
    url: endpoint,
    success : function(i){
      newlabels = i.newlabels
      newdata = i.newdata
      console.log(newdata) // working in console

      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: newlabels, // CHANGED 
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: newdata,  // CHANGED
            }]

          }
      })

    },  // FIRST ONE 
  error : function(error_data){
        console.log('error')
        console.log(error_data)} 

  })
</script>
```

**Getting this result** 
[image]

Comment: Show us what you see in the console, the value for `newdata`.

Comment: [Array(6)]
0: (6) [111, 22, 21, 113, 14, 15]
length: 1

Comment: [Array(6)]
0: (6) ["black", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple"]

Comment: The value of new data is same i have given in views.py

Comment: It is solved little mistake in code.